# Odoo change width popup

Tags: python, css, xml, odoo, formview

Anybody knows how or where to change the width of a popup form in Odoo. This may apply to all models.

I already found a module to edit the width of a standard form view. But I also want to change the width of a popup form view.

Comment: I think the template is in `/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml` file.

There you can find `t-name="CrashManager.warning"` template.

Comment: Look into the [web modules of OCA](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/b8e1337079b4d240dce1651cf4322dfebb349233) especially into `web_dialog_size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concerning css class is .modal-lg

Include a style sheet

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="custom_css" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_module_name/static/src/css/your_css_file"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

with this code

`.modal-lg {
    width: 80%
}`